# Mysterious execution order of "alert" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
<h1 id="title">foo</h1>

<script>
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('title').innerText = 'bar';
        alert("alert");
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

When I executed the above code, I expected to display "bar".
However, it was displayed "foo".

After that, when I press the "OK" button on the alert dialog, "bar" is displayed.

JavaScript is a single thread.
Unless it is asynchronous processing, it should be executed in order from the top of the source code.

Please explain the behavior of this "alert"

## sample

https://codepen.io/crystalcode/pen/aEygOZ/

Thank you.

Comment: Press F5 on the browser after saving script, maybe script caching?

Comment: Javascript alert stops the process till you click on `OK` or close it.